# python dicts - convert the values on an existing dict from lists to sets

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set, dictionary-comprehension

I have a dictionary that consists of strings for keys and lists for values.  I keep running into errors when trying to convert the values into sets.

Here is an example:

```
>>> dict = {'hello': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'w': [0], 'c': [2, 3], 'dog': [4]}
```

The closest I've gotten is this, but then I run into 'too many values to unpack' errors when trying to merge that back into the dict via a comprehension:

```
>>> [set(v) for v in dict.values()]
[{0, 1, 2, 3}, {0}, {2, 3}, {4}]
```

I've tried to convert from tuples too, but still keep running into either 'unhashable type' or 'too many values to unpack' errors depending on the approach.  Any tips?

Comment: `{k:set(v) for k, v in d.items()}` works for me. Probably shouldn't clobber the builtin `dict` by using it as a variable name, though.

Comment: thanks, I kept using .values() and didn't reach for the obvious solution.  much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert to dict using dict comprehension.

```
dict = {'hello': [0, 1, 2, 3], 'w': [0], 'c': [2, 3], 'dog': [4]}

{k : set(v) for k, v in dict.items()}

# Output
# {'hello': {0, 1, 2, 3}, 'w': {0}, 'c': {2, 3}, 'dog': {4}}
```

Comment: thanks, I was making this way to complicated by using .values() and just plain dict.